# Как вывести таблицу через console.log?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как вывести таблицу в консоль.
К примеру нужно вывести таблицу Пифагора. 
Картинка ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главное требование сохранить форматирование и сделать чтобы первая ячейка была пустой.

Comment: ccылка тут битая.

Comment: 1. Сохранить форматирование - каждое число добиваете пробелами до фиксированной ширины. 2. Чтобы первая ячейка была пустой - выводите там пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Если это табличные данные, то может их удобнее будет выводить в `Console.table()`

Answer (score 1):

Первые 3х3, дальше по аналогии.

```js
console.table([[4, 6, 8], [6, 9, 12], [8, 12, 16]]);
```